# Bound continuous function in interval using a convex function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, continuity

Given a continuous function $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$, I want to prove that there is a convex function $ g$ such that: 
1. $g(x) \ge f(x) , x\in [a,b]$
2. $g(a) = f(a)$
3. There is $p\in (a,b]$ such that $g(p) = f(p)$

Is it true?

Comment: Can you find such a line to $f(x) = x(1-x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Such a line doesn't always exist. Consider a function $f$ like $f(x)=\sqrt{x-a}$ whose slope becomes unbounded near $a$.

Comment: Just what I was thinking, but for $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @user284015 - I edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Consider the (continous) function $f(x) = x(1-x)$ defined on $[0,1]$. Let $y(x) = mx + n$ be your line. If $y(0) = f(0)$ then clearly $n=0$. Since $f'(0) = 1$ and we demand that $f(x) \leq y(x) \forall x\in [a,b]$ we must have $m \geq 1$. However, then there is no $p \in (0,1]$ with $y(p) = f(p)$.

Comment: I edited the question @Lionel Ricci